# Trying to run SonarScanner with gradle on the open-source Conversations app

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, sonarscanner

To learn about SonarQube I'm using the open-source app called [Conversations](https://github.com/iNPUTmice/Conversations) and I'm trying to run SonarScanner with gradle. I have directly cloned the project from git and added the following configuration in the build.grade:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
  }
}
dependencies {
classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.8"
}
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

And when I run the command "gradle sonarqube" in the root folder I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileConversationsPlaystoreSystemDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

I don't understand how to run sonarscanner with gradle and would appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: i do not think that this is related to sonarqube, can you run `gradle build` - it seems like the project does not compile. the task which is failing has nothing to do with sonarqube scanner